# Background image position relative to browser view-port instead of full website length

Tags: css

I'm trying to align a image to position at the bottom of the website, however, it aligns at the bottom of the browser and therefore leaves a gap when scrolling down.

Here's current code:

```
    .pbg{
  background: #e1feff url("http://d.cjshort.co.uk/img/mountains.png") no-repeat;
  background-position: center bottom;
   }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Create a jsfiddle to show what the problem is.

Comment: Can you provide a Fiddle with more code? We can't work off this alone. I'm guessing you are looking for background-attachment.

Answer (score 0):

By default browsers apply margin to the  tag, that might be causing the gap you're seeing at the bottom of the page. You can do something like `body { margin: 0; }` or use a full-fledge css reset.

But like others have said, it's not super clear exactly what the problem you're having is.